# sql update table using the case

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE [Current]  
SET   
    C_OS = CASE WHEN [Current].[OS] <> [viLastRecord].[OS] THEN '1' END,  
    C_VER = CASE WHEN [Current].[VER] <> [viLastRecord].[VER] THEN '1' END  
WHERE
    [Current].VHOST = viLastRecord.VHOST AND  
    [Current].HOSTNAME = viLastRecord.HOSTNAME
```

If I run this query, I got the following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "viLastRecord.VHOST" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "viLastRecord.HOSTNAME" could not be bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `join` because `viLastRecord` is a table and it is not defined in the query.

Judging by the syntax, it looks like you are using SQL Server.  So, you can try this:

```
UPDATE c 
    SET C_OS = (CASE WHEN c.[OS] <> vlr.[OS] THEN '1' END),  
        C_VER = (CASE WHEN c.[VER] <> vlr.[VER] THEN '1' END)  
    FROM [Current] c JOIN
         viLastRecord vlr
         ON c.VHOST = vlr.VHOST AND  
            c.HOSTNAME = vlr.HOSTNAME;
```